# What does it mean to use a string that was input from the user as a format-control and why is it a security breach?

Tags: java

I read this Error Prevention Tip (3.1) in Deitel and Deitel's book, *Java: How to Program*. I do not understand what it means. I only know that it was talking about the line of code below:

```
// display the name stored in object myAccount
System.out.printf("Name in object myAccount is:%n%s%n", myAccount.getName());
```

The paragraph is as follows:

> Never use as a format-control a string that was input from the user. When method `System.out.printf` evaluates the format-control string in its first argument, the method performs tasks based on the conversion specifier(s) in that string. If the format-control string were obtained from the user, a malicious user could supply conversion specifiers that would be executed by `System.out.printf`, possibly causing a security breach.

Comment: Off the top of my head, a malicious user could inject a format specifier which determines the _length_ (read: number of characters) of a certain string in your code which is displayed to the console.  Then, you might be leaking information which was never intended for users to see.

Comment: This is a much, much bigger problem in C, where a malicious format string can be used to print arbitrary data from the stack, or even write things to memory with the `%n` specifier.

Comment: I tried entering an input that includes specifiers like %s or %n but they are printed the same way, they are not read as specifiers, so I don't know how this could be causing any problem since if I am not mistaken the compiler evaluates the first argument and pastes the second argument-the user input- where %s was in the first argument.

Comment: I don't think the quote applies to that line of code. That `printf` is fine. A bad `printf` is one that has a user input variable in the first argument, like `System.out.printf("My name is " + myAccount.getName() + "%n")`.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, using a string input by the user for format-control would be like this:

```
String format=getFromUser(...);
System.out.printf(format, arg1, arg2, arg3...);
```

This could be really harmful because, apart of the coding injection suggested by @JohnKugelman, I can think of *four easy ways* in which a malicious user could break security through a [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

- The simplest is by entering a wrong mask, so that a `WrongFormatConversion` would be thrown at runtime:

```
    @Test
    public void wrongMask()
    {
        String s="january";
        System.out.printf("%)/$#", s);
    }
```

- By entering a high argument index, so that a `MissingFormatArgumentException` would be thrown at runtime:

```
    @Test
    public void highArgumentIndex()
    {
        String s="january";
        System.out.printf("%1000$s%n", s);
    }
```

- By entering a high field width, so that such a huge line would be outputed, that it would be impractical to read:

```
    @Test
    public void highFieldWidth()
    {
        String s="january";
        System.out.printf("%1000000s%n", s);
    }
```

- Idem, but specifying a zero-padding high width for a number argument, so that the padding operation would consume a long time and possibly high memory too (surely because the padding algorithm was not intended to handle big strings, and so, it was not designed to be optimal).

```
    @Test
    public void highArgumentWidth()
    {
        int n=12;
        System.out.printf("%01000000d%n", n);
    }
```

This test delayed almost **one minute** to be executed on my computer. Try with a high enough width and you'll probably get an `OutOfMemoryError` after several minutes of delay.

(Code injection is easily avoidable through a simple pre-processing of the input string to escap all double-quotes, but these flaws are of *semantic nature*, so they are harder to find and avoid).

But none of these can be applied to your line, because your format string is hard-coded, not input from user.

### Update

To understand how dangerous is to accept a control format string from the final user, you'd better repeat the upper set of tests, but in an interactive mode:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String format=args[0];
        int n=12;
        System.out.printf(format, n);
    }
```

Then, imagine yourself as a hacker trying to break this program. Execute it with these proposed values:

- `%)/$#`
- `%1000$d`
- `%1000000d`
- `%01000000d`

Conclussion: The format string must be composed by the programmer, not by the final interactive user.

Comment: Thanks @LittleSanti, but I still don't quiet see your point. So focusing on the first type of error you mentioned, I tried the code on my computer but it only failed because there is no format specifier after the % sign, in this case "s". It had nothing to do with anything else. Simple syntax error.

I guess what I have understood from this statement is that something like

    String a1 = "s";
    String a2 = "january";
    System.out.printf("%s",a1,a2);

and then expect "january" to be printed.

Comment: To further explain my confusion, in the first type you mentioned the only source of error is the programmer. If I take the input "january" from the user, there is (as far as I know) nothing the user could enter instead of "january" that would cause a problem or be considered a(n) attack/breach. So, since the first argument of printf is processed before the user input is replaced in it and printed, the output is always going to be what the user typed. No manipulation can take place because processing the format specifiers is already done. Isn't that true?

Comment: Yes, you are right, @Max. I see my explanation was not completely clear. See my update.